# ffmpeg ERROR: libnpp not found in windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cuda, nvenc

I`m trying to compile ffmpeg in windows with nvidia libraries for hardware acceleration using MinGW/msys. tried to follow the instruction on [nvidias website](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg) (section: Getting Started with FFmpeg/libav using NVIDIA GPUs). configured with **--enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-Ilocal/include --extra-cflags=-I../common/inc --extra-ldflags=-L../common/lib/x64 --prefix=ffmpeg** but stopped at **"ERROR: libnpp not found."** where common folder is downloaded from [NVIDIA Video Codec SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk#Download)  but there is no npp libs or header files. is there any solution for that? thanks for edvice.

Comment: Go and download the CUDA toolkit. NPP is distributed as part of that

Comment: Or just don't build with NPP support

Comment: I have already tried it. installed cuda toolkit, found npp libs and headers and copied them to common/lib/x64 and common/inc folders but still not works...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to successfuly cross compile *ffmpeg* under linux targeting Windows 64 bit with **--enable-libnpp** included.

My environment is Ubuntu Server 16.10 64bit.
After a fresh installation I installed MinGW using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

First I successfully compiled the Linux version with the **--enable-libnpp** option activated following the instructions on the NVIDIA dev site [Compile Ffmpeg with NVIDIA Video Codec SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg).
In order to do that you need to install the [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Just follow the instructions and the package installer will create the symbolic links (I have the CUDA Toolkit 8.0):

> /usr/local/cuda/include/ -> /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -> /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib

This should provide *Configure* the right path to find the correct libraries and headers.
The command line I have used to compile the linux version of ffmpeg is:

```
./configure --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

The problem you got is that when using cross-compilation you need to provide *Configure* the right path where to find headers and library for the Windows version of the **libnpp** library.
From the CUDA Toolkit Download page mentioned above I simply downloaded the *exe(local)* version of the Windows package.
Under the root of my working folder I created a folder called *tmp* where I copied the subfolders I found under *npp_dev* inside the package *cuda_8.0.61_win10.exe*:

```
cuda_8.0.61_win10.exe\npp_dev\lib -> tmp/lib  
cuda_8.0.61_win10.exe\npp_dev\include -> tmp/include
```

As final step I launched *Configure* once again using the following parameters:

```
./configure --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ --extra-cflags=-I../tmp/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L../tmp/lib/x64/
```

The compilation completed successully. When I copied the *ffmpeg.exe* file to Windows and tried to execute it I got an errore message saying the executable was missing some npp_*.dll.
From the package *cuda_8.0.61_win10.exe* I copied all the dlls included into the folder ***npp\bin*** to the same directory I put *ffmpeg.exe*.
After that the application run normally and a simple conversion from a 4K file completed as expected.

Comment: on Ubuntu you should use `dpkg-query -L cuda-npp-dev-10-0` (or your NPP package name) to figure out which paths are the NPP include and lib directories

Answer (score 8):

Actually I went nuts about ffmpeg is not building with the same problem. I fianally managed to get it worked under Windows 10 x64:

1. Download msys2 from https://www.msys2.org/ and install all packages with Pacman
2. `pacman -Su`
3. `pacman -S make`
4. `pacman -S diffutils`
5. `pacman -S yasm`
6. `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`
7. `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`
8. add pkgconfig to environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
9. Add additional installed toolchain to path: `PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin`
10. Start mingw64 version: `C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64`
11. Download and install Cuda from nVidia https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork
12. Extract the downloaded file e.g. `cuda_11.2.2_461.33_win10.exe` with 7zip locally
13. Copy `cuda_nvcc\nvcc\include` to your msys2 e.g. `C:\msys64\tmp\nvidia_include`
14. Copy `libnpp\npp_dev\lib\x64` to your `C:\msys64\tmp\nvidia_lib\x64`
15. Copy `libnpp\npp_dev\include` to `C:\msys64\tmp\nvidia_npp_include`
16. `git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git` to `C:\msys64\home\<user>`
17. `git clone https://github.com/libav/libav` to `C:\msys64\home\<user>`
18. Maybe optional step: `git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git` to `C:\msys64\home\<user>`
19. `make`
20. `make install`
21. Optional because make install should have done this for you: Copy ffnvcodec.pc to `C:\msys64\usr\local\lib\pkgconfig`
22. Build libav `avconv.exe` and `avprobe.exe` are needed for ffmpeg later:
23. `cd C:\msys64\home\<user>\libav`
24. `./configure`
25. `make`
26. `make install`
27. Finally build ffmpeg:
28. `cd C:\msys64\home\<user>\ffmpeg`
29. `./configure --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/tmp/nvidia_npp_include --extra-cflags=-I/tmp/nvidia_include --extra-ldflags=-L/tmp/nvidia_lib/x64`
30. `make`
31. `make install`
32. Copy `avconv.exe` and `avprobe.exe` to ffmpeg directory

Done.

Bugfixing:

- Missing DLLs: find x64 missing DLLs on your harddisk or in internet.
- Use dependency walker for analyzing errors
- Download the newest nVidia drivers and use nSight making sure CUVID is supported for your graphic card.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together, I went through all stages but was not able to resolve all the nVidia files in section 3, as the new 11.1 offering has moved the files around (I downloaded and installed the local installation not the network one, hope that wasn't the issue!). So the exact directories required were not there, and I think that derailed my attempt.

Comment: @topspeed today I wanted to redo all the steps on my new computer and I failed too. I corrected the steps above for section 3. All the includes and libs are found in the downloaded file from nVidia.

Comment: Missing DLLs
libwinpthread-1.dll
libbz2-1.dll
libiconv-2.dll
liblzma-5.dll
can be found in the \mingw64\bin\ folder
copy them to ffmpeg folder after compile

Answer (score 3):

This would seem to be caused by a broken configuration script in the FFmpeg code base. There is no library called npp in recent CUDA distributions, instead on Windows platforms you will have

```
nppc.lib
nppi.lib
npps.lib
```

and on linux

```
libnppc.so
libnppi.so
libnpps.so
```

You will either need to modify the configuration system yourself or file a bug request with the project developers to do it for you.

There might still be additional problems building the project with MinGW, but that is way beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: thanks for your answer talonmies, but the only solution i found was that i configured ffmpeg with --disable-libnpp flag...

Comment: Same here. I can't get libnpp detected to save my life. I'll just have to settle with disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

If you check config.log, there may have a lot link warnings:
`LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/L...'; ignored`
cause
`ERROR: libnpp not found`.
Since /L is not a correct argument for msvc linker, in order to include library path, the argument should as follow:
`./configure .... --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/... --extra-ldflags=-LIBPATH:/usr/local/cuda/...` 
This should able to solve the libnpp not found issue.
FYI, linker options are listed in the following link (included **LIBPATH**):
[Linker Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

### 2022 Update

On this weekend I also managed to build latest **ffmpeg** with working scale_npp filter. Without any npp missing library error during compilation and building. But with some caveats (see below).

I followed [this guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/) by NVIDIA with installed NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit `v11.7` and latest driver display `473.47` for my video card GeForce GT 710 on Windows 10 21H2 x64

#### Changes (adaptations) for steps in the guide

I copied all headers **including folders** from directory `path_to_CUDA_toolkit/include`

I excluded `pkg-config` from pacman packages, because after recommended installation steps ([step 7](https://www.msys2.org/) in particular) of MSYS2 it conflicts with installed `pkgconf` package, i.e. use this command instead:

```bash
pacman -S diffutils make yasm
```

I added **directories to Visual Studio** C compiler **to PATH environment variable in advance** (using Windows GUI), in addition to declaring them in the MinGW64 terminal as specified in the guide:

```bash
export PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/":$PATH
export PATH="/d/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/bin/":$PATH
```

After making (building) **ffnvcodec** headers, define `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (where compiled file `ffnvcodec.pc` is located) before configure command.

**Use absolute paths** for  `--extra-cflags` and `--extra-ldflags` options of configure command. *It's probably the main thing in solving "not found" errors. But don't forget that these paths will be printed in ffmpeg banner with other explicit build options*.

```bash
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/d/_makeit/nv-codec-headers/" ./configure --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --toolchain=msvc --extra-cflags="-I/d/_makeit/ffmpeg/nv_sdk/" --extra-ldflags="-LIBPATH:/d/_makeit/ffmpeg/nv_sdk/"
```

And that's it. At least `-vf scale_npp` should work.

In my case still DO NOT WORK the following things from the guide:

- <strike>cuda built-in *resizer* and *cropper*</strike>, i.e. `-hwaccel_output_format cuda –resize 1280x720` and `-hwaccel_output_format cuda –crop 16x16x32x32`. I bet that this is due to my old video card is not in [GPU Support Matrix](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new). But NVENC and NVDEC works fine for me *almost without crutches*. And it seems I'm [note alone](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/441859/ffmpeg-with-cuda-filters-nvidia-example-does-not-w/?topicPage=2).
  **UPD:** *resizer* and *cropper* **work!** BUT in the mentioned guide commands are incorrect. I found correct way in another [NVIDIA FFmpeg Transcoding Guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/). Decoder `h264_cuvid` was missed, must be so:

```bash
ffmpeg.exe -y -vsync passthrough -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -resize 1280x720 -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4

ffmpeg.exe -y -vsync passthrough -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -crop 16x16x32x32 -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4
```

- `-vf scale_cuda` fails with error. Maybe I used wrong C compiler version or didn't install DirectX SDK from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk/download) or installed wrong packages after installing MSYS2 and ignoring `pkg-config`

```
[Parsed_scale_cuda_0 @ 000001A461479DC0] cu->cuModuleLoadData(cu_module, data) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_PTX_VERSION: the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain.
```

- there is no possibility to use `-preset` option for `h264_nvenc` with **latest** ffmpeg version where presets (enum) were updated. I noticed from ffmpeg report file, this is because using any preset causes "auto" enabling lookahead mode with log raw:
  `[h264_nvenc @ 00000158EFC6E500] Lookahead enabled: depth 28, scenecut enabled, B-adapt enabled.`
  Even though the options `-rc-lookahead` and `-temporal-aq` are not supported by my device (video card). I have to use only one preset **p4** (medium) which is by default. *And I don't know how to workaround this issue.* Value 0 for `-rc-lookahead` also does not help.
- specifying `-bf 2` only works with option `-extra_hw_frames 6` *(six in my case - number of extra frames can differ for your card)*. Or using only `-bf 0`. But this is due to constraints of my old video card.

```
ffmpeg.exe -v verbose -y -vsync passthrough -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 6 -i input-1080p.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 1M -bf 2 -bufsize 1M -maxrate 2M -qmin 0 -g 250 -b_ref_mode middle -i_qfactor 0.75 -b_qfactor 1.1 output.mp4
```

I hope my notes will help future Google and SO users.